# Background colour of text area not changing

Tags: javascript, html

I have this javascript function which should take 3 values representing rub from 3 different text areas, then change a different text area's background colour accordingly:

```
 function rbg() {
    document.getElementById("textarea").style.backgroundColor = "rgb("
    + document.getElementById("rvalue").value + "," 
    + document.getElementByID("gvalue").value + "," 
    + document.getElementByID("bvalue").value +")";
    }
```

Here's the html:

```
<input id="textarea" type="text" name="sometext">
 Enter RGB Values: 
<input id="rvalue" type="text" maxlength=3 value ="0" name="r" onBlur="rgb()">
<input id="gvalue" type="text" maxlength=3 value ="0" name="g" onBlur="rgb()">
<input id="bvalue" type="text" maxlength=3 value ="0" name="b" onBlur="rgb()">
```

The issue is the background of the the text area will not change at all, and I can't work out why!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a typo in the code. The onBlur function executes"rgb()" but the function is called "rbg()"

Comment: You also use `document.getElementByID`, and the D should not be capitalized. Running your code with a console window open will show you errors like that immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is called `rbg`, but you bind to `rgb`. Also, the function is [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) (not `ID`). Update as follows:

```
function rgb() 
{
    document.getElementById("textarea").style.backgroundColor = "rgb("
        + document.getElementById("rvalue").value + "," 
        + document.getElementById("gvalue").value + "," 
        + document.getElementById("bvalue").value +")";
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ezmgaqmx/)

Comment: Does anyone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: I didn't find the downvote appropriate so I upvoted to counteract. Your solution looks correct.

Comment: Why is this - https://jsfiddle.net/maz7a78s/1/   -  not working? any ideas?

Comment: @TheGuest Because you had the JS wrapped `onLoad`. Try setting it to `no wrap <head>`.

Comment: @TheGuest https://jsfiddle.net/maz7a78s/2/

Comment: @BenM It's been a while since I used jsFiddle, recently the UI in jsFiddle is changed. Thank you so much for your time to working on my issue

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById()` not `document.getElementByID()`

`rgb()` not `rbg()`

Please check your console before posting questions.

```js
function rgb() {
  document.getElementById("textarea").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" +
    document.getElementById("rvalue").value + "," +
    document.getElementById("gvalue").value + "," +
    document.getElementById("bvalue").value + ")";
}
```

```html
<input id="textarea" type="text" name="sometext">Enter RGB Values:
<input id="rvalue" type="text" maxlength=3 value="0" name="r" onBlur="rgb()">
<input id="gvalue" type="text" maxlength=3 value="0" name="g" onBlur="rgb()">
<input id="bvalue" type="text" maxlength=3 value="0" name="b" onBlur="rgb()">
```

Comment: Also, note `rgb` vs `rbg`. (See my answer)

Comment: Why not just upvote the answer already posted, instead of going to the trouble of editing your own?

Comment: Because I voted for the answer to be closed... Just posted it to help the OP (with the inline example) I don't think this is useful to anyone else

Comment: I also voted to close the question, but don't understand why you wouldn't just upvote the answer already there!

Comment: @BenM Because in my mind, an upvote means that the answer is useful to others. Again I only posted an answer to help the OP, but the spirit of SO is to help others?

Comment: But surely that's not mutually exclusive on the question being useful to others? Surely an upvote should be added for the quality of the answer on its own merits (sources, samples and clear explanations)?

Comment: @BenM I'm not sure, if you point me to a meta question/answer that says so, I will happily change my mind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105306/discussion-between-juan-mendes-and-benm).